# enabling clipboard for firefox portable?

Tags: firefox, clipboard, portability

i'm using the xinha wysiwyg editor and would like to enable the clipboard (for using the  menu icons: copy, cut, paste)

i've googled but couldn't find a working method - only for adding some settings capability.policy.allowclipboard.Clipboard to the user.js

unfortunately my firefox portable has no user.js :(

can someone tell me where to add those settings?

thx,
fuxi

Answer (score 1):

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard is pretty clear. There's an extension that manages the prefs for you. And there is support for user settings (via user.js too) in Firefox portable. The file just doesn't exist by default (but neither does it exist in the normal Firefox) and the profile of portable Firefox is at a non-standard location (on the flash stick too).